# Scrolling to active accordion header in modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

quick question that's been breaking my balls.

I have an jquery ui accordion (.accordion) that opens another accordion (.glossWrap) in a modal. I'm trying to get the active accordion header to scroll into view with scrollTop but is just glitches out or something.

```
$(".glossary").on("click", function () {
$(".glossWrap").accordion({heightStyle:"content", header:"h3", navigation : true, collapsible:true})
var $accordion = $(".glossWrap"),
panelId = parseInt(window.location.hash.replace(/#panel/, "")) || 0;
var $this = $(this), toOpen = $this.data("panel");
$accordion.accordion("option", "active", toOpen), ( "option", "collapsible", true );
} );

$('.glossary').click(function(){ setTimeout(  function(){
$('#pageslide').animate({
scrollTop: $(".ui-accordion-content-active").offset().top}, 2000);
}, 800) });
```

I use the setTimeOut to wait before the modal opens.

html: accordion 1 with links too .glossWrap accordion 2

```
    <div class="accordion">
  <h3 id="accordion">accordion 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p><a href="#" data-panel="1" class="glossary">open accordion item in modal</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Accordion in pageslide:

```
<div id="pageslide">
<div class="glossWrap" >
  <div class="glossIndexWrap">
    <h2>A</h2>
    <h3>glossWrap</h3>
    <!--1-->
    <div>
      <p>open this and scroll into view</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your suggestions! :)

greetz, Will

Comment: Have you tried `.position()` instead of `.offset()` ... `.offset()` usually means the relative position of the element to it's positioned parent. Just a shot in the dark, can look more in depth soon! :)

Comment: tried this immediately but position does not nothing, are you sure that is even possible? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working, I now know it has something to do with my nested divs within a modal. After trying a couple of different plugins I went with this one: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

This worked perfectly within my accordion!

cheers!